Count color range pixels from histogram?
I have a image with gif format like following:

I want to create a color range with the color #444641 and a fuzziness of 157. After that, I want to retrieve the count of pixels for each color from the histogram, like the following example:

I tried following command in in cmd:
magick convert "E:/Desktop/inflation/tst/0115.gif" -fill none -draw "matte 444641 157" -format "%c" histogram:info:-

but this command show some info like following!
    25: (206,205,201,255) #CECDC9FF srgba(206,205,201,1)
277604: (206,207,202,255) #CECFCAFF srgba(206,207,202,1)
  5009: (206,208,203,255) #CED0CBFF srgba(206,208,203,1)
   368: (206,211,205,255) #CED3CDFF srgba(206,211,205,1)
   905: (207,206,202,255) #CFCECAFF srgba(207,206,202,1)
   166: (207,208,203,255) #CFD0CBFF srgba(207,208,203,1)
  2131: (207,209,204,255) #CFD1CCFF srgba(207,209,204,1)
   289: (207,212,206,255) #CFD4CEFF srgba(207,212,206,1)
    10: (208,207,203,255) #D0CFCBFF srgba(208,207,203,1)
    93: (208,209,204,255) #D0D1CCFF srgba(208,209,204,1)
  1040: (208,210,205,255) #D0D2CDFF srgba(208,210,205,1)
    42: (209,210,205,255) #D1D2CDFF srgba(209,210,205,1)
   496: (209,211,206,255) #D1D3CEFF srgba(209,211,206,1)
    17: (210,211,206,255) #D2D3CEFF srgba(210,211,206,1)
   287: (210,212,207,255) #D2D4CFFF srgba(210,212,207,1)
   200: (210,213,208,255) #D2D5D0FF srgba(210,213,208,1)
     7: (211,212,207,255) #D3D4CFFF srgba(211,212,207,1)
   140: (211,214,209,255) #D3D6D1FF srgba(211,214,209,1)
   168: (213,216,211,255) #D5D8D3FF srgba(213,216,211,1)

I don't want this. I need Uncached pixels count number! this mean I need 63031 pixels number in output.
where is my command problem!?

I do not understand what you mean by uncached. Your image has a total of 1412640 pixels.  Where do you get 63031?  How many counts do you get from adding up all those counts in the histogram that I showed.

Your Imagemagick command makes no sense to me where it says -draw "matte 444641 157". I do not understand why it does not object. The format for the -draw matte command is matte x,y method, see https://imagemagick.org/script/magick-vector-graphics.php. Perhaps you wanted the floodfill method. Also on Imagemagick 7, use magick, not magick convert. Nevertheless ...
Perhaps what you are trying to do is:
magick.exe "E:/Desktop/inflation/tst/0115.gif -fuzz 157 -fill none -opaque "#444641" -format "%c" histogram:info:-


Is your Imagemagick version Q8 or Q16. Is 157 out of 255 (8-bit value) or out of 65535 (16-bit value).  If you meant 157 out of 255 on Q8 or you meant 157 out of 65535 and on Q16, then that is OK, but if you wanted 157 out 255 on Q16, then you need to convert that to percent 157/65535=0.24% and use -fuzz 0.24%. I note that 157/255=61.5% would be a very large fuzz value. So that is not likely. So I will assume you wanted 157 out 65535 and on Q16.
For the equivalent command on my Mac Imagemagick 7.1.1.31 Q16, I get
  4320: (0,0,0,0) #00000000 none
    76: (56,59,54,255) #383B36FF srgba(56,59,54,1)
   225: (59,62,57,255) #3B3E39FF srgba(59,62,57,1)
   254: (61,63,58,255) #3D3F3AFF srgba(61,63,58,1)
   141: (61,66,60,255) #3D423CFF srgba(61,66,60,1)
     3: (62,63,58,255) #3E3F3AFF srgba(62,63,58,1)
   378: (62,64,59,255) #3E403BFF srgba(62,64,59,1)
   165: (62,67,61,255) #3E433DFF srgba(62,67,61,1)
    23: (62,69,62,255) #3E453EFF srgba(62,69,62,1)
     5: (63,64,59,255) #3F403BFF srgba(63,64,59,1)
   651: (63,65,60,255) #3F413CFF srgba(63,65,60,1)
   258: (63,68,62,255) #3F443EFF srgba(63,68,62,1)
    24: (63,70,63,255) #3F463FFF srgba(63,70,63,1)
    15: (64,65,60,255) #40413CFF srgba(64,65,60,1)
  1059: (64,66,61,255) #40423DFF srgba(64,66,61,1)
   366: (64,69,63,255) #40453FFF srgba(64,69,63,1)
    25: (65,66,61,255) #41423DFF srgba(65,66,61,1)
  1706: (65,67,62,255) #41433EFF srgba(65,67,62,1)
   603: (65,70,64,255) #414640FF srgba(65,70,64,1)
    24: (65,72,65,255) #414841FF srgba(65,72,65,1)
    55: (66,67,62,255) #42433EFF srgba(66,67,62,1)
  2363: (66,68,63,255) #42443FFF srgba(66,68,63,1)
   897: (66,71,65,255) #424741FF srgba(66,71,65,1)
    72: (67,68,63,255) #43443FFF srgba(67,68,63,1)
  3163: (67,69,64,255) #434540FF srgba(67,69,64,1)
  1218: (67,72,66,255) #434842FF srgba(67,72,66,1)
    22: (67,74,67,255) #434A43FF srgba(67,74,67,1)
   120: (68,69,64,255) #444540FF srgba(68,69,64,1)
  1142: (68,73,67,255) #444943FF srgba(68,73,67,1)
  4550: (69,71,66,255) #454742FF srgba(69,71,66,1)
  1091: (69,74,68,255) #454A44FF srgba(69,74,68,1)
    14: (69,76,69,255) #454C45FF srgba(69,76,69,1)
   237: (70,71,66,255) #464742FF srgba(70,71,66,1)
  4707: (70,72,67,255) #464843FF srgba(70,72,67,1)
   951: (70,75,69,255) #464B45FF srgba(70,75,69,1)
     7: (70,77,70,255) #464D46FF srgba(70,77,70,1)
   236: (71,72,67,255) #474843FF srgba(71,72,67,1)
  3881: (71,73,68,255) #474944FF srgba(71,73,68,1)
   828: (71,76,70,255) #474C46FF srgba(71,76,70,1)
   192: (72,73,68,255) #484944FF srgba(72,73,68,1)
  3234: (72,74,69,255) #484A45FF srgba(72,74,69,1)
   657: (72,77,71,255) #484D47FF srgba(72,77,71,1)
     8: (72,79,72,255) #484F48FF srgba(72,79,72,1)
   149: (73,74,69,255) #494A45FF srgba(73,74,69,1)
  2407: (73,75,70,255) #494B46FF srgba(73,75,70,1)
   558: (73,78,72,255) #494E48FF srgba(73,78,72,1)
     2: (73,80,73,255) #495049FF srgba(73,80,73,1)
   115: (74,75,70,255) #4A4B46FF srgba(74,75,70,1)
  1887: (74,76,71,255) #4A4C47FF srgba(74,76,71,1)
   441: (74,79,73,255) #4A4F49FF srgba(74,79,73,1)
   101: (75,76,71,255) #4B4C47FF srgba(75,76,71,1)
  1634: (75,77,72,255) #4B4D48FF srgba(75,77,72,1)
   349: (75,80,74,255) #4B504AFF srgba(75,80,74,1)
    72: (76,77,72,255) #4C4D48FF srgba(76,77,72,1)
  1268: (76,78,73,255) #4C4E49FF srgba(76,78,73,1)
   255: (76,81,75,255) #4C514BFF srgba(76,81,75,1)
    60: (77,78,73,255) #4D4E49FF srgba(77,78,73,1)
  1061: (77,79,74,255) #4D4F4AFF srgba(77,79,74,1)
   195: (77,82,76,255) #4D524CFF srgba(77,82,76,1)
    46: (78,79,74,255) #4E4F4AFF srgba(78,79,74,1)
   840: (78,80,75,255) #4E504BFF srgba(78,80,75,1)
   161: (78,83,77,255) #4E534DFF srgba(78,83,77,1)
    35: (79,80,75,255) #4F504BFF srgba(79,80,75,1)
   640: (79,81,76,255) #4F514CFF srgba(79,81,76,1)
   250: (79,85,79,255) #4F554FFF srgba(79,85,79,1)
    37: (80,81,76,255) #50514CFF srgba(80,81,76,1)
   523: (80,82,77,255) #50524DFF srgba(80,82,77,1)
    19: (81,82,77,255) #51524DFF srgba(81,82,77,1)
   399: (81,83,78,255) #51534EFF srgba(81,83,78,1)
    96: (81,86,80,255) #515650FF srgba(81,86,80,1)
    29: (82,83,78,255) #52534EFF srgba(82,83,78,1)
   385: (82,84,79,255) #52544FFF srgba(82,84,79,1)
    12: (83,84,79,255) #53544FFF srgba(83,84,79,1)
   325: (83,85,80,255) #535550FF srgba(83,85,80,1)
   229: (83,88,82,255) #535852FF srgba(83,88,82,1)
    18: (84,85,80,255) #545550FF srgba(84,85,80,1)
   280: (84,86,81,255) #545651FF srgba(84,86,81,1)
    19: (85,86,81,255) #555651FF srgba(85,86,81,1)
   260: (85,87,82,255) #555752FF srgba(85,87,82,1)
   140: (85,90,84,255) #555A54FF srgba(85,90,84,1)
    20: (86,87,82,255) #565752FF srgba(86,87,82,1)
   261: (86,88,83,255) #565853FF srgba(86,88,83,1)
   233: (87,89,84,255) #575954FF srgba(87,89,84,1)
   221: (88,90,85,255) #585A55FF srgba(88,90,85,1)
   231: (88,91,86,255) #585B56FF srgba(88,91,86,1)
    89: (88,93,87,255) #585D57FF srgba(88,93,87,1)
   195: (90,92,87,255) #5A5C57FF srgba(90,92,87,1)
   110: (90,95,89,255) #5A5F59FF srgba(90,95,89,1)
   188: (91,93,88,255) #5B5D58FF srgba(91,93,88,1)
   170: (92,94,89,255) #5C5E59FF srgba(92,94,89,1)
     9: (93,94,89,255) #5D5E59FF srgba(93,94,89,1)
   170: (93,95,90,255) #5D5F5AFF srgba(93,95,90,1)
   155: (94,96,91,255) #5E605BFF srgba(94,96,91,1)
   201: (94,97,92,255) #5E615CFF srgba(94,97,92,1)
    75: (94,99,93,255) #5E635DFF srgba(94,99,93,1)
   135: (96,98,93,255) #60625DFF srgba(96,98,93,1)
   242: (98,100,95,255) #62645FFF srgba(98,100,95,1)
   208: (98,101,96,255) #626560FF srgba(98,101,96,1)
   183: (99,103,97,255) #636761FF srgba(99,103,97,1)
   255: (102,104,99,255) #666863FF srgba(102,104,99,1)
   239: (103,106,100,255) #676A64FF srgba(103,106,100,1)
   103: (103,108,102,255) #676C66FF srgba(103,108,102,1)
   220: (105,107,102,255) #696B66FF srgba(105,107,102,1)
   136: (106,110,104,255) #6A6E68FF srgba(106,110,104,1)
   140: (108,110,105,255) #6C6E69FF srgba(108,110,105,1)
   209: (110,111,106,255) #6E6F6AFF srgba(110,111,106,1)
   189: (110,113,108,255) #6E716CFF srgba(110,113,108,1)
   215: (113,115,110,255) #71736EFF srgba(113,115,110,1)
   133: (113,117,111,255) #71756FFF srgba(113,117,111,1)
   109: (115,117,112,255) #737570FF srgba(115,117,112,1)
   182: (117,119,114,255) #757772FF srgba(117,119,114,1)
   146: (117,120,115,255) #757873FF srgba(117,120,115,1)
   146: (118,122,116,255) #767A74FF srgba(118,122,116,1)
   189: (121,122,117,255) #797A75FF srgba(121,122,117,1)
   247: (122,125,119,255) #7A7D77FF srgba(122,125,119,1)
   151: (123,126,121,255) #7B7E79FF srgba(123,126,121,1)
   221: (126,127,122,255) #7E7F7AFF srgba(126,127,122,1)
   161: (126,129,124,255) #7E817CFF srgba(126,129,124,1)
   234: (129,130,125,255) #81827DFF srgba(129,130,125,1)
   169: (129,132,127,255) #81847FFF srgba(129,132,127,1)
   144: (130,134,128,255) #828680FF srgba(130,134,128,1)
   142: (132,134,129,255) #848681FF srgba(132,134,129,1)
   231: (134,135,130,255) #868782FF srgba(134,135,130,1)
   192: (134,137,132,255) #868984FF srgba(134,137,132,1)
   169: (135,139,133,255) #878B85FF srgba(135,139,133,1)
   106: (137,142,136,255) #898E88FF srgba(137,142,136,1)
   251: (138,139,134,255) #8A8B86FF srgba(138,139,134,1)
   255: (140,142,137,255) #8C8E89FF srgba(140,142,137,1)
   198: (140,144,138,255) #8C908AFF srgba(140,144,138,1)
   123: (142,144,139,255) #8E908BFF srgba(142,144,139,1)
   167: (143,145,140,255) #8F918CFF srgba(143,145,140,1)
   138: (144,146,141,255) #90928DFF srgba(144,146,141,1)
   191: (144,147,142,255) #90938EFF srgba(144,147,142,1)
   191: (145,149,143,255) #91958FFF srgba(145,149,143,1)
   158: (147,149,144,255) #939590FF srgba(147,149,144,1)
   175: (148,150,145,255) #949691FF srgba(148,150,145,1)
   160: (149,151,146,255) #959792FF srgba(149,151,146,1)
   211: (149,152,147,255) #959893FF srgba(149,152,147,1)
    65: (149,154,148,255) #959A94FF srgba(149,154,148,1)
   163: (151,153,148,255) #979994FF srgba(151,153,148,1)
   172: (152,154,149,255) #989A95FF srgba(152,154,149,1)
   150: (153,155,150,255) #999B96FF srgba(153,155,150,1)
   212: (153,156,151,255) #999C97FF srgba(153,156,151,1)
   102: (154,159,153,255) #9A9F99FF srgba(154,159,153,1)
   174: (155,157,152,255) #9B9D98FF srgba(155,157,152,1)
   129: (156,157,152,255) #9C9D98FF srgba(156,157,152,1)
    75: (156,161,155,255) #9CA19BFF srgba(156,161,155,1)
   147: (157,159,154,255) #9D9F9AFF srgba(157,159,154,1)
   268: (159,161,156,255) #9FA19CFF srgba(159,161,156,1)
   212: (159,162,157,255) #9FA29DFF srgba(159,162,157,1)
     9: (161,162,157,255) #A1A29DFF srgba(161,162,157,1)
   143: (161,163,158,255) #A1A39EFF srgba(161,163,158,1)
   144: (162,164,159,255) #A2A49FFF srgba(162,164,159,1)
   223: (162,165,160,255) #A2A5A0FF srgba(162,165,160,1)
    69: (162,167,161,255) #A2A7A1FF srgba(162,167,161,1)
   158: (164,166,161,255) #A4A6A1FF srgba(164,166,161,1)
   159: (165,167,162,255) #A5A7A2FF srgba(165,167,162,1)
   248: (167,169,164,255) #A7A9A4FF srgba(167,169,164,1)
   224: (167,170,165,255) #A7AAA5FF srgba(167,170,165,1)
    70: (167,172,166,255) #A7ACA6FF srgba(167,172,166,1)
    78: (169,174,168,255) #A9AEA8FF srgba(169,174,168,1)
   260: (170,171,166,255) #AAABA6FF srgba(170,171,166,1)
   251: (172,174,169,255) #ACAEA9FF srgba(172,174,169,1)
   162: (172,175,170,255) #ACAFAAFF srgba(172,175,170,1)
   191: (173,177,171,255) #ADB1ABFF srgba(173,177,171,1)
   167: (175,177,172,255) #AFB1ACFF srgba(175,177,172,1)
   161: (176,178,173,255) #B0B2ADFF srgba(176,178,173,1)
   147: (177,179,174,255) #B1B3AEFF srgba(177,179,174,1)
   233: (177,180,175,255) #B1B4AFFF srgba(177,180,175,1)
    97: (177,182,176,255) #B1B6B0FF srgba(177,182,176,1)
   159: (179,181,176,255) #B3B5B0FF srgba(179,181,176,1)
   186: (180,182,177,255) #B4B6B1FF srgba(180,182,177,1)
   211: (180,183,178,255) #B4B7B2FF srgba(180,183,178,1)
   105: (180,185,179,255) #B4B9B3FF srgba(180,185,179,1)
   197: (182,184,179,255) #B6B8B3FF srgba(182,184,179,1)
   200: (183,185,180,255) #B7B9B4FF srgba(183,185,180,1)
   184: (184,186,181,255) #B8BAB5FF srgba(184,186,181,1)
   279: (184,187,182,255) #B8BBB6FF srgba(184,187,182,1)
   218: (186,188,183,255) #BABCB7FF srgba(186,188,183,1)
   294: (186,189,184,255) #BABDB8FF srgba(186,189,184,1)
    93: (186,191,185,255) #BABFB9FF srgba(186,191,185,1)
   205: (188,190,185,255) #BCBEB9FF srgba(188,190,185,1)
    69: (188,193,187,255) #BCC1BBFF srgba(188,193,187,1)
   203: (189,191,186,255) #BDBFBAFF srgba(189,191,186,1)
   201: (190,192,187,255) #BEC0BBFF srgba(190,192,187,1)
   220: (190,195,189,255) #BEC3BDFF srgba(190,195,189,1)
   216: (191,193,188,255) #BFC1BCFF srgba(191,193,188,1)
   233: (192,194,189,255) #C0C2BDFF srgba(192,194,189,1)
    90: (192,197,191,255) #C0C5BFFF srgba(192,197,191,1)
     8: (193,194,189,255) #C1C2BDFF srgba(193,194,189,1)
   264: (193,195,190,255) #C1C3BEFF srgba(193,195,190,1)
   113: (193,198,192,255) #C1C6C0FF srgba(193,198,192,1)
    12: (194,195,190,255) #C2C3BEFF srgba(194,195,190,1)
   371: (194,196,191,255) #C2C4BFFF srgba(194,196,191,1)
   143: (194,199,193,255) #C2C7C1FF srgba(194,199,193,1)
     9: (195,196,191,255) #C3C4BFFF srgba(195,196,191,1)
   413: (195,197,192,255) #C3C5C0FF srgba(195,197,192,1)
   197: (195,200,194,255) #C3C8C2FF srgba(195,200,194,1)
    19: (196,197,192,255) #C4C5C0FF srgba(196,197,192,1)
   570: (196,198,193,255) #C4C6C1FF srgba(196,198,193,1)
   282: (196,201,195,255) #C4C9C3FF srgba(196,201,195,1)
     8: (196,203,196,255) #C4CBC4FF srgba(196,203,196,1)
    26: (197,198,193,255) #C5C6C1FF srgba(197,198,193,1)
   755: (197,199,194,255) #C5C7C2FF srgba(197,199,194,1)
   399: (197,202,196,255) #C5CAC4FF srgba(197,202,196,1)
    25: (198,199,194,255) #C6C7C2FF srgba(198,199,194,1)
  1090: (198,200,195,255) #C6C8C3FF srgba(198,200,195,1)
   629: (198,203,197,255) #C6CBC5FF srgba(198,203,197,1)
    21: (198,205,198,255) #C6CDC6FF srgba(198,205,198,1)
    32: (199,200,195,255) #C7C8C3FF srgba(199,200,195,1)
  1590: (199,201,196,255) #C7C9C4FF srgba(199,201,196,1)
  1056: (199,204,198,255) #C7CCC6FF srgba(199,204,198,1)
    57: (199,206,199,255) #C7CEC7FF srgba(199,206,199,1)
    55: (200,201,196,255) #C8C9C4FF srgba(200,201,196,1)
  2404: (200,202,197,255) #C8CAC5FF srgba(200,202,197,1)
  1839: (200,205,199,255) #C8CDC7FF srgba(200,205,199,1)
    76: (200,207,200,255) #C8CFC8FF srgba(200,207,200,1)
    70: (201,202,197,255) #C9CAC5FF srgba(201,202,197,1)
  3794: (201,203,198,255) #C9CBC6FF srgba(201,203,198,1)
  3350: (201,206,200,255) #C9CEC8FF srgba(201,206,200,1)
   645: (201,208,201,255) #C9D0C9FF srgba(201,208,201,1)
   108: (202,203,198,255) #CACBC6FF srgba(202,203,198,1)
  6656: (202,204,199,255) #CACCC7FF srgba(202,204,199,1)
 45407: (202,207,201,255) #CACFC9FF srgba(202,207,201,1)
  1564: (202,209,202,255) #CAD1CAFF srgba(202,209,202,1)
   185: (203,204,199,255) #CBCCC7FF srgba(203,204,199,1)
 11321: (203,205,200,255) #CBCDC8FF srgba(203,205,200,1)
430077: (203,208,202,255) #CBD0CAFF srgba(203,208,202,1)
    49: (203,210,203,255) #CBD2CBFF srgba(203,210,203,1)
   346: (204,205,200,255) #CCCDC8FF srgba(204,205,200,1)
126330: (204,206,201,255) #CCCEC9FF srgba(204,206,201,1)
  1756: (204,209,203,255) #CCD1CBFF srgba(204,209,203,1)
    17: (204,211,204,255) #CCD3CCFF srgba(204,211,204,1)
  4739: (205,206,201,255) #CDCEC9FF srgba(205,206,201,1)
400017: (205,207,202,255) #CDCFCAFF srgba(205,207,202,1)
   768: (205,210,204,255) #CDD2CCFF srgba(205,210,204,1)
    25: (206,205,201,255) #CECDC9FF srgba(206,205,201,1)
277604: (206,207,202,255) #CECFCAFF srgba(206,207,202,1)
  5009: (206,208,203,255) #CED0CBFF srgba(206,208,203,1)
   368: (206,211,205,255) #CED3CDFF srgba(206,211,205,1)
   905: (207,206,202,255) #CFCECAFF srgba(207,206,202,1)
   166: (207,208,203,255) #CFD0CBFF srgba(207,208,203,1)
  2131: (207,209,204,255) #CFD1CCFF srgba(207,209,204,1)
   289: (207,212,206,255) #CFD4CEFF srgba(207,212,206,1)
    10: (208,207,203,255) #D0CFCBFF srgba(208,207,203,1)
    93: (208,209,204,255) #D0D1CCFF srgba(208,209,204,1)
  1040: (208,210,205,255) #D0D2CDFF srgba(208,210,205,1)
    42: (209,210,205,255) #D1D2CDFF srgba(209,210,205,1)
   496: (209,211,206,255) #D1D3CEFF srgba(209,211,206,1)
    17: (210,211,206,255) #D2D3CEFF srgba(210,211,206,1)
   287: (210,212,207,255) #D2D4CFFF srgba(210,212,207,1)
   200: (210,213,208,255) #D2D5D0FF srgba(210,213,208,1)
     7: (211,212,207,255) #D3D4CFFF srgba(211,212,207,1)
   140: (211,214,209,255) #D3D6D1FF srgba(211,214,209,1)
   168: (213,216,211,255) #D5D8D3FF srgba(213,216,211,1)

Is this more what you want?

what is 65535 number!! - I tried multiple times by photoshop and all of my numbers didn't bigger than 63000

65535 would be the maximum value of the data for any pixel in your image if you were using 16-bit data rather than 8-bit data. That is pure white would be 65535. If you got 63000, then that means you do not have any pure white in your image, but slightly darker.
